# Dead letter queue topic not getting created as KAFKA Admin client times out for listTopics method

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, sasl, aws-msk

I am trying to enable `dead letter` on my `JDBC Sink Connector`. In sink connector configuration, I have provided following properties -

```
'errors.tolerance'='all',
'errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name' = 'error_topic',
'errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor'= -1
```

But while creating the Sink connector, I am getting following error -

> {"message":"Failed to start task MY_SINK_CONNECTOR-0","level":"ERROR","mdc": {"connector.context":"[MY_SINK_CONNECTOR|task-0] "},"@timestamp":"2022-06-02T14:28:08.043Z","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker","thread_name":"StartAndStopExecutor-connect-1-3","stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not initialize dead letter queue with topic=error_topic\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.DeadLetterQueueReporter.createAndSetup(DeadLetterQueueReporter.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.sinkTaskReporters(Worker.java:784)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.buildWorkerTask(Worker.java:622)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:545)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1421)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$getTaskStartingCallable$22(DistributedHerder.java:1434)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1654180088021, tries=2, nextAllowedTryMs=1654180088137) timed out at 1654180088037 after 2 attempt(s)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.DeadLetterQueueReporter.createAndSetup(DeadLetterQueueReporter.java:84)\n\t... 9 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1654180088021, tries=2, nextAllowedTryMs=1654180088137) timed out at 1654180088037 after 2 attempt(s)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled listTopics request with correlation id 6 due to node 1 being disconnected"}

From the Error it seems like, Kafka Admin client is timing out while calling listTopics. We are using `SASL_SSL` security protocol and `AWS_MSK_IAM` as `sasl mechanism` . Are there any reason why list topics can timeout?

Comment: It times out if it cannot authenticate. Did you define any of the authentication properties for the admin client in the connect worker?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @OneCricketeer, It was a problem with authentication as we enabled kms encryption for our MSK cluster.

Comment: If you've solved this problem, please show your solution as an answer below